# No encuetra id y no funciona el botón

Tags: javascript

Tengo el siguiente problema. Tengo un botón que debería mostrar un modal con un formulario en su interior, pero el navegador me lanza el siguiente mensaje de error:

> *Uncaught ReferenceError: formRol is not defined*

El código que tengo es:

- Archivo function_roles.js:

```
    var formRol = document.querySelector("#formRol");
    formRol.onsubmit = function(e)
    {
        e.preventDefault();
        var intIdRol = document.querySelector('#idRol').value;
        var strNombre = document.querySelector('#txtNombre').value;
        var strDescripcion = document.querySelector('#txtDescripcion').value;
        var intStatus = document.querySelector('#listStatus').value;
        if (strNombre == '' || strDescripcion=='' || intStatus=='') 
        {
            swal("Atención", "Todos los campos son obligatorios", "Error");
            return false;
        }...
```

y el archivo donde está el modal es:

```
    <div class="modal fade" id="modalFormRol" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header headerRegister">
    <h5 class="modal-title" id="titleModal">Nuevo Rol</h5>
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
    <div class="tile">
    <div class="tile-body">
    <form id="formRol" name="formRol">
    <input type="hidden" id="idRol" name="idRol" value="">
    <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label">Nombre</label>
    <input class="form-control" id="txtNombre" name="txtNombre" type="text" placeholder="Nombre del rol" 
    required="">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label">Descripcion</label>
    <textarea class="form-control" id="txtDescripcion" name="txtDescripcion" rows="2" 
    placeholder="Descripcion del rol" required=""></textarea>
    </div>
                
    <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleSelect1">Estado</label>
    <select class="form-control" id="listStatus" name="listStatus" required="">
    <option value="1">Activo</option>
    <option value="2">Inactivo</option>
    </select>
    </div>
    <div class="tile-footer">
    <button id="btnActionForm" class="btn btn-primary" type="submit"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-lg fa-check- 
    circle"></i><span id="btnText">Guardar</span></button>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a class="btn btn-secondary" 
    href="#" data-dismiss="modal"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-lg fa-times-circle"></i>Cancelar</a>
    </div>
    </form>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>

Alguien puede ayudarme con este error? me tiene loco y no sé cómo solucionarlo.
Gracias.
```

Comment: ¿Tienes el código _Javascript_ arriba del formulario? Entonces ese es el problema, el formulario todavía no existe cuando intentas acceder. Pasa el código hasta abajo, antes de `</body>` o colócalo en una función que se ejecute hasta que se haya cargado el DOM.

Answer (score 0):

*Bueno lo que dice ese error es: formRol no esta definido lo que puedes hacer es verificar con console log*

**Algo como esto**

*y revisar si llega algo o que pasa en el transcurso que realizas esas acciones*

```
var formRol = document.querySelector("#formRol");

<!-- Bueno aquí verificamos que es lo que nos devuelve -->
console.log(formRol);



<!-- o talvez intenta agarrar al formulario con --> 
var formRol = document.getElementbyId("formRol");
console.log(formRol);
```

```
formRol.onsubmit = function(e)
{
    e.preventDefault();
    var intIdRol = document.querySelector('#idRol').value;
    var strNombre = document.querySelector('#txtNombre').value;
    var strDescripcion = document.querySelector('#txtDescripcion').value;
    var intStatus = document.querySelector('#listStatus').value;
    if (strNombre == '' || strDescripcion=='' || intStatus=='') 
    {
        swal("Atención", "Todos los campos son obligatorios", "Error");
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Prueba cambiar el 'querySelector' con un 'getByElementId'
El código te quedaría así:

```
var formRol = document.getElementById("formRol");
formRol.onsubmit = function(e)
{
    alert();
    e.preventDefault();
    var intIdRol = document.getElementById('idRol').value;
    var strNombre = document.getElementById('txtNombre').value;
    var strDescripcion = document.getElementById('txtDescripcion').value;
    var intStatus = document.getElementById('listStatus').value;
    if (strNombre == '' || strDescripcion=='' || intStatus=='') 
    {
        swal("Atención", "Todos los campos son obligatorios", "Error");
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Gracias por las respuestas, pero como era de esperar, console.log(formRol) de vuelve null, y cambiando por `var formRol = document.getElementById("formRol");`, sigue dando el mismo error.

Comment: ¿Podrias mostrar más del archivo function_roles.js?

Answer (score 0):

Este es el archivo function_roles.js:

```
var tableRoles;

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){

tableRoles = $('#tableRoles').DataTable( {
    "Processing":true,
    "aServerSide":true,
    "language": {
    "url": "//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.21/i18n/Spanish.json"
    },
    "ajax":{
    "url": ""+base_url+"/Roles/getRoles",
    "dataSrc":""
    },
    "columns":[
    {"data":"idrol"},
    {"data":"nombrerol"},
    {"data":"descripcion"},
    {"data":"status"},
    {"data": "options"}
    ],
    "responsive":"true",
    "bDestroy":true,
    "iDisplayLength": 10,
    "order":[[0,"desc"]]
    });

    //NUEVO ROL
    formRol = document.querySelector("#formRol");
    console.log(formRol);
    formRol.onsubmit = function(e)
    {
    alert();
    e.preventDefault();
    var intIdRol = document.getElementById('idRol').value;
    var strNombre = document.getElementById('txtNombre').value;
    var strDescripcion = document.getElementById('txtDescripcion').value;
    var intStatus = document.getElementById('listStatus').value;
    if (strNombre == '' || strDescripcion=='' || intStatus=='') 
    {
    swal("Atención", "Todos los campos son obligatorios", "Error");
    return false;
    }

    var request = (window.XMLHttpRequest) ? new XMLHttpRequest() : new   ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
    var ajaxUrl = base_url+'/Roles/setRol';
    var formData = new FormData(formRol);
    request.open("POST", ajaxUrl, true);
    request.send(formData);
    request.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if (request.readyState == 4 && request.status == 200) {

    var objData = JSON.parse(request.responseText);

    if(objData.status){
    $('#modalFormRol').modal("hide");
    formRol.reset();
    swal("Roles de usuario", objData.msg, "success");
    tableRoles.ajax.reload(function(){

    fntEditRol();
    });
    } else {
    swal("Error", objData.msg, "error");
    }
    }
            
            
    }
    }

});

    $('#tableRoles').DataTable();

    function openModal()
    {
    document.querySelector('#idRol').value = "";
    document.querySelector('.modal-header').classList.replace("headerUpdate",     "headerRegister");
    document.querySelector('#btnActionForm').classList.replace("btn-info", "btn-primary");
    document.querySelector('#btnText').innerHTML = "Guardar";
    document.querySelector('#titleModal').innerHTML = "Nuevo Rol";
    document.querySelector("#formRol").reset();
    $('#modalFormRol').modal('show');
    }

    window.addEventListener('load', function(){
    fntEditRol();
    fntDelRol();
    }, false);

    function fntEditRol(){
    var btnEditRol = document.querySelectorAll(".btnEditRol");
    btnEditRol.forEach(function(btnEditRol){
    btnEditRol.addEventListener('click', function(){

    document.querySelector('#titleModal').innerHTML = "Actualizar Rol";
    document.querySelector('.modal-header').classList.replace("headerRegister", "headerUpdate");
    document.querySelector('#btnActionForm').classList.replace("btn-primary", "btn-info");
    document.querySelector('#btnText').innerHTML = "Actualizar";

    var idrol = this.getAttribute("rl");
    var request = (window.XMLHttpRequest) ? new XMLHttpRequest() : new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
    var ajaxUrl = base_url+'/Roles/getRol/'+idrol;
    request.open("GET", ajaxUrl,true);
    request.send();

    request.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if (request.readyState == 4 && request.status == 200) {
                    
    var objData = JSON.parse(request.responseText);

    if (objData.status) 
    {
    document.querySelector("#idRol").value = objData.data.idrol;
    document.querySelector("#txtNombre").value = objData.data.nombrerol;
    document.querySelector("#txtDescripcion").value = objData.data.descripcion;

    if (objData.data.status == 1) 
    {
    var optionSelect = '<option value="1" selected class="notBlock">Activo</option>';

    }else{

    var optionSelect = '<option value="2" selected class="notBlock">Inactivo</option>';
    }

    var htmlSelect ='${optionSelect}
    <option value="1">Activo</option>
    <option value="2">Inactivo</option>
    ';
    document.querySelector("#listStatus").innerHTML = htmlSelect;
    $('#modalFormRol').modal('show');
    }else{
    swal("Error", objData.msg, "error");
    }
    }
    }
    
    });
    });
    }

function fntDelRol(){
    var btnDelRol = document.querySelectorAll(".btnDelRol");
    btnDelRol.forEach(function(btnDelRol){
    btnDelRol.addEventListener('click', function(){
    var idrol = this.getAttribute("rl");

    swal({
    title: "Eliminar rol",
    text: "¿Realmente quiere eliminar el rol?",
    type: "warning",
    showCancelButton: true,
    confirmButtonText: "Si, eliminar!",
    calcelButtontext: "No, cancelar!",
    closeOnConfirm: false,
    closeOnCancel: true
    }, function(isConfirm){

    if(isConfirm){
    var request = (window.XMLHttpRequest) ? new XMLHttpRequest() : new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
    var ajaxUrl = base_url+'/Roles/delRol/';
    var strData = "idrol="+idrol;
    request.open("POST",ajaxUrl,true);
    request.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    request.send(strData);
    request.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if(request.readyState = 4 && request.status == 200){
    var objData = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
    if(objData.status){
    swal("Eliminar!", objData.msg, "success");
    tableRoles.ajax.reload(function(){
    fntEditRol();
    fntDelRol();
    });
    } else{ 
    swal("Atencion!", objData.msg, "error");
    }
    }
    }
    }
    });

    });
    });
}
```

y este es el archivo del modal:

```
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="modalFormRol" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header headerRegister">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="titleModal">Nuevo Rol</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="tile">
            <div class="tile-body">
              <form id="formRol" name="formRol">
                <input type="hidden" id="idRol" name="idRol" value="">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label class="control-label">Nombre</label>
                  <input class="form-control" id="txtNombre" name="txtNombre" type="text" placeholder="Nombre del rol" required="">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label class="control-label">Descripcion</label>
                  <textarea class="form-control" id="txtDescripcion" name="txtDescripcion" rows="2" placeholder="Descripcion del rol" required=""></textarea>
                </div>
                
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="exampleSelect1">Estado</label>
                    <select class="form-control" id="listStatus" name="listStatus" required="">
                      <option value="1">Activo</option>
                      <option value="2">Inactivo</option>
                     </select>
                </div>
                <div class="tile-footer">
                <button id="btnActionForm" class="btn btn-primary" type="submit"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-lg fa-check-circle"></i><span id="btnText">Guardar</span></button>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a class="btn btn-secondary" href="#" data-dismiss="modal"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-lg fa-times-circle"></i>Cancelar</a>
                </div>
              </form>
            </div>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Por si te aclara algo te mando los dos archivos.
Gracias.